# Cube: Passing one dimension current member inside the argument of another dimension

Tags: mdx, olap, measures

In OLAP cube, while creating calculated measures, is it possible to pass the current member of one dimension (say [Dimension_Two]) as a parameter of Lead() or Lag() functions for another dimension ([Dimension_One])? 
Something like this:

> Sum( PERIODSTODATE ( [Dimension_One].[All].level,
>   [Dimension_One].CurrentMember.Lead([Dimension_Two].[Dimension_Hierarcy].CurrentMember)
>   ) ,[Measures].[Cost] )

Comment: Have tried using linkedmember? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146058.aspx

Comment: You can use the `CurrentMember` of each hierarchy in all calculations.